# Can Azure DevOps Projects be customized?

Tags: azure-devops

I would like to add some custom fields to a Azure DevOps Project.
By default, there are only two fields available: Name and Description.

[image]

However, I would like to add additional information to the project like internal ProjectNo, OrderNo, OfferNo, Offer Date and so on.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware there isn't any way to custom this aspect currently. You could always add it as a suggestion here; https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html.

Alternatively, depending on what you are looking to accomplish and how you want to use these new fields, could you make these 'projects' Epics (or create another Work Item type) under a 'global project'? If so you can easily customise work items to include these fields.

Comment: I already thought about creating an own Work Item Type and add the needed fields to it - this is my Plan B for now. Thx for your input though...